# Error al procesar la peticion codigo de error: 500 Texto error: internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo ese error al intentar ver la vista de diseño, necesito ver las relaciones de mis tablas, he conectado valet-linux y descargado phpmyadmin en paths de valet

cuando investigo solo pillo para agregar código al raíz de phpmyadmin al fichero `config.inc.php` el siguiente codigo php

```
    /* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';*/
```

y eso no me funciona

Comment: No entiendo la situación planteada aquí: por un lado muestras la interfaz gráfica de phpmyadmin con un mensaje de error que suele ocurrir cuando has iniciado sesión desde esa interfaz de forma exitosa y dicha sesión se cierra después de un tiempo determinado de inactividad; por otra parte muestras un código PHP que no veo la relación que éste tenga con la interfaz gráfica de phpmyadmin ¿?

Comment: he buscado por internet para solucionar ese error de phpmyadmin y los que encontre solo fue para agragar dicho codigo php en la raiz de phpmyadmin y no me soluciona el problema que estoy teniendo

Comment: Hola, Encontraste algun remedio a este problema? Estoy harta, desde que actualice el SO no consigo hacer funcionar mi database local.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es lo que a mi me sirvió:

-Prueba entrar en el archivo:**/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php**

-Editar **&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))**

-Por esto **&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))**

-Listo